# Is there a proof for the following Resummation formula?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

While reading the paper (https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1464-4266/5/3/363/pdf) I encountered the following resummation formula:
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sum_{r=0}^{n}a_{n,r}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sum_{r=0}^{\infty}a_{n+r,r}
$$

It is easy to see that these are the same by writing out a few terms of the sums on both sides of the equation but I cannot seem to find a proof. I would appreciate some help with this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, it’s probably only true if the sum is absolutely convergent.

Comment: As @ThomasAndrews says, you need absolute convergence to be able to freely rearrange the terms.

Comment: To given a counterexample where it isn’t true, this example from Rudin: $$a_{n,r}=\begin{cases}0&r>n\\-1&r=n\\\frac1{2^{n-r}}&r<n\end{cases}$$ Then $$\sum_{r=0}^{n}a_{n,r}=\frac1{2^n}+\frac1{2^{n-1}}+\cdots+\frac12+(-1)=-\frac1{2^n},$$ so the left hand sum is $-2.$ But $$\sum_{r=0}^{\infty}a_{n+r,r}=-1+\frac12+\frac14+\cdots =0,$$ so the right hand side is $0.$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming $\sum_{n = 0}^\infty \sum_{r = 0}^n |a_{n,r}| <\infty$, we have that
\begin{align*}
   \sum_{n = 0}^\infty \sum_{r = 0}^n a_{n,r} &= \sum_{n = 0}^\infty \sum_{r = 0}^\infty \big(\mathbb{I}\{r\le n\}\cdot a_{n,r} \big) = \sum_{r = 0}^\infty \sum_{n = 0}^\infty \big(\mathbb{I}\{r\le n\}\cdot a_{n,r} \big) 
\\
&= \sum_{r = 0}^\infty \sum_{n = r}^\infty  a_{n,r} = \sum_{r = 0}^\infty \sum_{n = 0}^\infty  a_{n+r,r} = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty \sum_{r = 0}^\infty  a_{n+r,r},
\end{align*}
where the second and the last equality follows from  $\sum_{n = 0}^\infty \sum_{r = 0}^n |a_{n,r}| <\infty$ and Fubini's theorem (for series).

Comment: Thank you for this answer. Could you please elaborate on what $\mathbb{I}\{r\leq n\}$ means?

Comment: It is the indicator function symbol. So, $\mathbb{I}\{r≤n\}$ is defined to be $1$ if $r≤n$, and $0$ if $r>n$

Comment: Thank you. Can you also clarify how the second lady equality follows from absolute convergence?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem

Comment: Thank you so much I really appreciate all the help.